# How to get the current Git branch name in a TFS 2013 build?

Tags: git, tfs, msbuild

### My goal

I want to include the current Git branch name in the name of my package (that is then deployed via Octopus).

If this was TFS 2015 or 2017, I could just set the Build number format to `$(SourceBranchName)-something` in the build definition. Or I could use the build variable `$(BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME)` in my `.proj` file.

But I am using TFS 2013, so these new variables are not available to me.

How do I achieve the same thing in TFS 2013?

### What I've tried

I attempted to get the branch name via a Git command:

```
<Exec Command="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" ContinueOnError="false" IgnoreExitCode="true" ConsoleToMsBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="CurrentGitBranch" />
</Exec>
```

But the output of this is just `HEAD`.

I also tried changing the command to:

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

Which returns `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`.

So it seems like the checked-out repository on the build server is not pointing to any specific branch.

Comment: I'm afraid TFS 2013 will check out a specific git commit and not a branch so there will be no "active" branch - this is when a `git status` would show `detached HEAD`. So I'm afraid you'll need to figure out a way for TFS build to pass in the branch name somehow as parameter / env var.

Comment: @MartinUllrich That's what I feared. Do you have any idea how to do this with TFS?

Comment: According to [a post I've found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0c88ae9-c028-4c46-aba3-9475f8a5e6fa/how-to-get-git-branch-name-in-prebuild-script?forum=tfsbuild) there's a `TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION` env var that has the branch name in it that could be extracted with a RegEx but can't test since I have no 2013 version.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Martin Ullrich, the current git branch is stored in the build variable `TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION`. The value stored is of the following format:

```
LG:refs/heads/branches/your-branch:71f12206f54365098b2d11cbf08844e82b664594
```

Not sure what `LG` is, but the second part is the branch name, and the last part is the commit hash. It's pretty easy to parse this information:

```
<Target Name="ParseGitInfo">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GitBranch>$(TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION.Split(':')[1])</GitBranch>
    <GitBranchName>$(GitBranch.Substring($([MSBuild]::Add($(GitBranch.LastIndexOf('/')), 1))))</GitBranchName>
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Target>
```

Comment: @Andy-MSFT Thanks! Done.